# Are there any times at all in the Harry potter series where Filch is actually being nice to anyone?

Tags: harry-potter

Are there any times at all in the Harry potter series where Filch is actually being nice to anyone?

Whether in the books or movies?

Or is he just mean to everybody?

Comment: Does Mrs Norris count?

Comment: "anyone" or just the good guys? He seems to be cool w/ Umbridge

Answer (score 12):

Filch is seen providing basic first aid to Snape in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

> Snape and Filch were inside, alone. Snape was holding his robes above his knees. One of his legs was bloody and mangled. Filch was handing Snape bandages.
>   ‘Blasted thing,’ Snape was saying.

And he's extremely polite to the new headmistress in Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix.

> Umbridge was sitting behind the desk, busily scribbling on some of her pink parchment, but she looked up and smiled widely at their entrance.
>   ‘Thank you, Argus,’ she said sweetly.
>   ‘Not at all, Ma’am, not at all,’ said Filch, bowing as low as his rheumatism would permit, and exiting backwards.